# What is best for Laravel Login?

Tags: laravel

I am creating an app, where they got different landing page when logged in, what is the best here multiple auth guard or login by usertype?

like multiple auth guard got different table for (admin, employee, user) while the usertype is there is column(usertype) in User table.

Multi Auth Example:

https://medium.com/hello-laravel/multiple-authentication-system-laravel-5-4-ac94c759638a

Usertype Example:

https://medium.com/justlaravel/how-to-use-middleware-for-content-restriction-based-on-user-role-in-laravel-2d0d8f8e94c6

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware and handle request something like this:

```
$guard = Auth::guard($guard);

        if ($guard->check()) {
            $user = $guard->user();

            if ($user->userType === 'admin') {
                return redirect('/adminPage');
            }    

        }

        return $next($request);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your `RedirectIfAuthenticated`  Middleware.

```
$guards = empty($guards) ? [null] : $guards;
$url = $request->url();
$url = explode("/",$url);

foreach ($guards as $guard) {
     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
         if (auth()->user()->type=="admin") {
              return redirect('super-admin/dashboard');
         } elseif (auth()->user()->type=="employee") {
              return redirect('employee/dashboard');
         } else {
              if ($url[3] == "admin" && $url) {
                  return redirect('admin/login');
               } else {
                   return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
               }
          }
      }
 }

return $next($request);
```